# How to get user-image from their email address

Tags: image, api, email, avatar

If a user is registering on my website using their email address, then Is it possible to get their profile-image(Avatar),if user has set some profile pic. Is there any API for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gravatar may be of use to you http://en.gravatar.com/

Comment: Gravatar may help me if the user is registered with it. if user is not on Gravatar then is there any way?

Comment: Do you mean the avatar registered on your site or say their gmail avatar?

Comment: Not sure that you can as this would depend on your Google+ privacy settings as to wether it is visable to all etc.